# Bash troubleshooting: Not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, loops, variables, vcftools

Beginner here trying to get a pipeline working in bash. If somebody can see why when I run the following I get:

```
-bash: `$i': not a valid identifier,
```

that would be really helpful. Also if there are other mistakes please let me know

```
for $i in /home/regionstextfile; do tabix /sequences/human_variation/snps/genotypes.vcf.gz $i | vcftools --window-pi 10000 >> /home/Testgenomesdata/genomesregions.txt; done
```

The idea is for each line in regionstextfile (which contains genome coordinates) run a program called `tabix` in the `vcf.bz` file, then with the output run `vcftools` with the specified options, then put all the outputs into the `genomesregions.txt` file.

Comment: Do the lines contain whitespace (spaces or tabs)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That must be so:

```
for i in `</home/regionstextfile`
do 
  tabix /sequences/human_variation/snps/genotypes.vcf.gz $i | vcftools --window-pi 10000 >> /home/Testgenomesdata/genomesregions.txt
done
```

When you use a variable (e.g. assign value to it or export it, or do anything but with the variable itself) you write its name without `$`; when you use a value of a variable you write `$`.

EDIT:

When region names contains spaces but each region is in a separate line, you need `while`:

```
cat /home/regionstextfile | while read i
do 
  tabix /sequences/human_variation/snps/genotypes.vcf.gz "$i" | vcftools --window-pi 10000 >> /home/Testgenomesdata/genomesregions.txt
done
```

Comment: As long as the lines in the textfile doesn't contain whitespace, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing without cat :

```
while read i
do
  tabix /sequences/human_variation/snps/genotypes.vcf.gz "$i" | vcftools --window-pi 10000 >> /home/Testgenomesdata/genomesregions.txt
done < /home/regionstextfile
```

Remark `<file.txt` could not work unless IFS=''

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=''
for i in `</home/regionstextfile`
do
  tabix /sequences/human_variation/snps/genotypes.vcf.gz $i | vcftools --window-pi 10000 >> /home/Testgenomesdata/genomesregions.txt
done
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```